# Custom shell in C - Result of pipelined processes comes after waiting for children and parent (Process Groups)

Tags: c++, shell, unix, process

I am writing my own shell in C/C++. I am implementing pipelined processes, but I have a weird issue on the output. Let's suppose I have the command `ls -al | grep something`. Since they are pipelined there should be two processes that are being forked and that run parallel. I am also using process groups to achieve this goal. My approach has been:
On a function for the job, inside a for loop, run for any intermediate process the code as should be expected: a `fork()`, the appropriate `setpgid(), tcsetpgrp()` calls for the child as well as any signal handling. If the function has reached the final process (e.g. `grep something` from the above example) run everything normally as above, but also add the waiting from the father.

The father waits for every process in a process group to end using the following code:

```
while(waitpid(-job->pgid, &status, WUNTRACED) != -1) {
   if (WSTOPSIG(status)) {
      break;
   }
};
```

If it detects the a child was stopped, it breaks so it does not wait any more for it. I am also checking for any zombie processes in the beginning of the main loop as show below:

```
std::string userInput;

while (1) {
        int pid;
        int status;

        while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED)) > 0) {
             // Caught zombie process
        }

        myshell_promt(); // Just a print
        std::getline(std::cin, userInput);
        if (userInput == "") { continue; }
        if (userInput == "exit") { break; }

        // Parse and execute command
        printf("Next command!\n");
}
```

Although it works fine (or so it seems) there are times where ,I guess due to context switching, I might get this result:

```
Next command!
-rw-r--r--  1 something something    536 Apr 19 18:25 something_else.cpp
mysc:> -rw-r--r--  1 something something    414 Apr 20 10:37 something.cpp
```

or

```
Next command!
mysc:> 
-rw-r--r--  1 something something    536 Apr 19 18:25 something_else.cpp
-rw-r--r--  1 something something    414 Apr 20 10:37 something.cpp
```

and then I wait for the next command from the user. However, this is not exactly what I want. I want the prompt to be after the result of the command , and I can't seem to figure out how to achieve this. What might be going wrong? Maybe something with giving the terminal back to the parent function (the shell)?

The following shows the execution for the processes, where forks are made:

```
pid_t childpid;
    int status = 0;

    childpid = fork();

    if (childpid < 0) {
        perror("Creating child process");
        return -1;
    } else if (childpid == 0) {
        // Update the process class to hold the correct pid
        proc->set_pid(getpid());

        // Will only get executed once per job
        // to set the job's group id to that of the first process' ID
        if (job->get_pgid() == -1 ) {
            // Initialize pgid, only for the first process
            job->set_pgid(proc->get_pid());
        }
      
        // Attach the process to the process group
        setpgid(0, job->get_pgid());

        signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGSTOP, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTTIN, SIG_DFL);
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL);

        // Play with pipes ...
        
        if (execvp(proc->argv[0], proc->argv) < 0) {
            printf("mysh: %s: command not found\n", proc->argv[0]);
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("Assert it does not come here!\n");
        exit(0);

    } else {
        // Same exact code as the child, in order to assure it doesn't matter which gets here first
        // the correct things will happen, and avoid races
        proc->set_pid(childpid);

        if (job->get_pgid() == -1 ) {
            job->set_pgid(proc->get_pid());
        }
        setpgid(childpid, job->get_pgid());
        
        // Only the last process will get called with the mode set as FOREGROUND_EXECUTION
        // So it can wait for all previous ones to end
        if (mode == FOREGROUND_EXECUTION) {
            // If foreground, set it to have control of the terminal
            // close pipes ...
            // give control of the terminal to the process group
            tcsetpgrp(0, job->get_pgid());
            // now wait for the job
            status = shell->wait_for_job(job->id);
            signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
            // Get back control of the terminal
            tcsetpgrp(0, getpid());
            signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL);
        }
    }

    return status;
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: processes are not gendered.  The parent is generally referred to as "parent", and not "father".

Comment: Rather than `printf("Assert it does not come here!\n");`, it would be more idiomatic to `assert(0)`

Comment: @a_confused_programmer – 
The error is probably in the code you didn't show.